# Add click event to tag <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm tryign  to add the click event on my  tag but It seems not working. I got always the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: ((m.event.special[e.origType] || (intermediate value)).handle || e.handler).apply is not a function
>
> at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3)
>
> at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3)

Here my code:

```
this.drawButtons = function(id,buttons) {
    var buttonsArea = $("#"+((id!=null)?id:"buttons"));
    buttonsArea.append("<div class='pull-right'><table><tr class='buttonsrow' ></tr></table></div>");
    if(buttons != null) {
        var row = $("");
        var a;
        for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++) {
            a = $("<a href='#' title='"+buttons[i].title+"' "+
                    "class='"+buttons[i].size+"-button' "+
                    "style='margin-right: 5px; margin-top: 3px; background-image:url(../images/buttons/"+buttons[i].image+");' ></a>");
            if(buttons[i].action!=null)
                a.click(buttons[i].action);
            buttonsArea.find(".buttonsrow").append($("<td></td>").append(a));
        }
    }       
}
```

The function that I pass is like this:

```
var prova = new function() {
    var buttons =
        [
            [
                {
                    title: "save",
                    size: "medium",
                    image: "save.png",
                    action: "prova.test1()"
                },
                {
                    title: "back",
                    size: "small",
                    image: "back.png",
                    action: "prova.showPage();"
                }
            ]
        ];
    this.showPage = function() {
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you call the function?

Comment: what is your `buttons[i].action` function?

Comment: can you also check if buttons[i].action is of type function? (ie, `if(buttons[i].action!=null || typeof buttons[i].action == 'function')`)

Comment: I have modified the text of the question with an example of prova that is a JS imported in the main page and visible from the method drawButtons, check it please